# Public index.html page title appears for sometime upon page load

Tags: reactjs

i am new to react and typescript. I have a site where page title is updated using react helmet. But the default page title which is there in public/index.html page appears for a flash when page is loading. How I can avoid that?

I am not sure what to do.

Comment: I recommend looking at the time line in the Network tab of your browser developer tools. There might not be anything you can do about this other than removing `<title>` tag from `index.html` entirely or else changing it to what you want to appear at the initial load.